# Big Integer class in C++. How to push digits in an array of unsigned long integers?

Tags: c++, string, biginteger

I am writing a simple big integer library for exercise. I would like to use it in a simple implementation of RSA. I have read all the previous threads but I have not found an answer to my question. I am just at the beginning of the project and I have read the best choice to represents all the digits of the big integer should be to represent them using an array of unsigned long numbers, so it should be something like this:

```
class BigInteger
{
   public:
      BigInteger(const std::string &digits);

   private:
      std::vector <unsigned long> _digits;
};
```

The problem is that I don't know how to implement the constructor of the class. I think I should convert every character of the string and save it in the array in a way which minimizes the overall memory used by the array because every character is 1 byte long while an unsigned long is at least 4 bytes long. Should I push a group of 4 characters at a time to avoid wasting every unsigned long digit memory? Could you give me an example or some suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to save the digits one by one - why not use char? (will waste memory too, as it could hold 256 states and you use it for 10 only, but at least only 1 byte instead of 4)

Comment: I have read it's suggested to use unsigned long instead of char. I think I'll understand it when I'll be going to implement the various operations.

Answer (score 3):

Before thinking about how to push digits, think about how to implement
the four basic operations.  What you want to do in the constructor from
string is to convert the string to the internal representation, whatever
that is, and to do so, you have to be able to multiply by 10 (supposing
decimal) and add.

Comment: Yes, but before implementing the four basic operations I should know what's the internal representation of the digits...

Comment: I think James means that you should take an look at how to do the operations with various ways of internal representation. You should be able to do them with least effort - no big transformations for every single arithmetic operation. Sometimes it is worth to "waste" some memory if it has an big impact on performance.

Comment: @JohnQ Yes and no.  You obviously can't implement the operations without knowing the representation, but you probably want to take potential implementations into account when deciding on the implementation.  At any rate, you can't implement the constructor from string until you can multiply by 10 and add, so it's a later consideration.

Comment: So there is no way to represent the number in base 2 using unsigned long integers?

Comment: Of course there is.  But you can't start converting a string representation to such a number before you've defined how you want to represent them, which in term depends on the operators + and *.  Or expressed differently: it's rather trivial to define how to convert the string to your internal representation, but that definition will use * and +, and will be indifferent to the rest of your class.

Answer (score 0):

As @James Kanze correctly points out, conversions to and from string are not the main design issue, and you should leave them until the end. If you focus on simplifying the interface with the outside world you might end up with a design that is easy to serialize but a nightmare to work with.

On the particular problem at hand, a common approach to dealing with bignumbers efficiently is using half of the bits in each storage unit (if your `unsigned long` is 32bits, use only the lower 16bits). Having the spare space in all units allow you to operate separatedly in each element without having to deal with overflows and then `normalize` the result by moving the carry-out (high bit numbers). A simplified pseuso-code approach to sum (ignoring sizes and mostly everything else would be:

```
bignumber& bignumber::operator+=( bignumber const & rhs ) {
   // ensure that there is enough space
   for ( int i = 0; i < size(); ++i ) {
      data[ i ] += rhs.data[ i ];       // might break invariant but won't overflow
   }
   normalize();                         // fix the invariant
}
// Common idiom: implement operator+ in terms of operator+= on the first argument 
//     (copied by value)
bignumber operator+( bignumber lhs, bignumber const & rhs ) {
   lhs += rhs;
   return lhs;
}
```

Comment: It is worth looking at the <boost/operators.hpp> class templates: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/utility/operators.htm - they can add these common idioms for you (i.e. implementing `+` in terms of `+=` can be done by specifying the `addable<T>` template)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to use this approach. But how could I use the lower 16 bits of 32 bits if a character is only 8 bits?

Comment: @JohnQ You've already been explained this.  For each digit, you multiply the running total by 10, then add the numeric value of the digit.  The fact that a character is 8 bits is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Oh ok, now I think I understand. Thanks to all.